# What is an Eclipse Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-project-file

What is is EclipseProject http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/

Comment: You just linked to their site--what are you trying to find out?

Answer (score 3):

Your link describes the human project structure to build the integrated development environment (IDE) called Eclipse.